# Dark mode without being logged in

Tags: feature-request, dark-mode

Is there a way to enable Stack Overflow's dark theme without being logged in?

I sometimes open an incognito window where I browse and end up on the Stack Overflow website. Also having a keyboard shortcut for this would be great!

Comment: You can get a similar result as the darkmode with browser addons like https://darkreader.org/

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/849930). If we get [this toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaA08.png) at some point, it will likely work without being logged in. It's been quite a long time though, so I'm not sure if there are still plans for that.

Comment: For the folks comfortable with Tampermonkey, you could write a script to change the `unified-theme` class on SO's `<body>` to `theme-dark` and things should _mostly_ work fine; there are some exceptions to this such as charts. This wouldn't work on network websites, however, since those sites haven't had their themes updated for dark mode.

Comment: I've turned on dark mode on most of the apps that I'm using (either through their settings or by setting system mode - also dark) and now whenever I end up on a website or app that doesn't have a dark theme is like getting a flashlight directly into my eyes.